# jqgrid update SelectCommand at runtime and listen for row select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

#### 1)

I am using the [`jqgrid`](http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx) plugin to show results from different selections a user can make on sliders and such. The jqgrid loads via a `php` command:

```
$grid->SelectCommand = 'MySQL SELECT statement here';
```

But I want to change this, and reload the data at runtime (via jquery) when the user makes a change.

(Also if possible I would like to know the number of results found so I can display it somewhere else bigger.)

#### 2)

Also when the user clicks on a row in the grid.. I want a js function to be called and the data from the row to be passed into the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out 2 of 3

### To listen for clicks:

#### myfirstgrid.php

```
$selectorder = <<<ORDER
function(rowid, selected) 
{ 
    if(rowid != null) { 
        alert("selected: "+rowid); 
    } 
} 
ORDER;
$grid->setGridEvent('onSelectRow', $selectorder);
```

---

### To update the SelectCommand

Make your page that sets it, listen for GET vars to build it from.

Then on your page you can change it with js like this:

#### main page

```
function changeSelectCommand(){
    $('#grid').setGridParam({url:'myfirstgrid.php?brand=stardust'}); 
    $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");  
};
```

#### myfirstgrid.php

```
....
$brand = $_GET['brand'] ? $_GET['brand'] : "nike"];
$grid->SelectCommand = 'SELECT product_id, product_name, product_brand, product_price FROM cart_product WHERE product_brand = "'.$brand.'"';
....
```

#### *I still havent figured out how to get number of results?*

Comment: Sorry but what language is this: 
$selectorder = <<<ORDER
function(rowid, selected) 
{ 
    if(rowid != null) { 
        alert("selected: "+rowid); 
    } 
} 
ORDER;
I am having errors while using it within php.